# Regex remove character from capturing group/workaround

Tags: regex

Suppose I have a String like following

`@ABCD|NN12CT55|GFR`

now I want to match

`@ABCD|N`

and replace it with

`@ABCD N`

regex for matching 
`@ABCD\|[^G]`

is there a way to remove the | from the capturing group?

Comment: `@(TEST)\|\1` replace with `@\1 \1`

Comment: @AvinashRaj its working for the given example, but i cant seem to adapt it into my needs. can you give me an solution for this? `@ABCD|NN12CT55|GFR` is input. and maybe a little explanation what it does?

Comment: Please update the question to show the real life scenario and explain what  is wrong with your regex. You do not even have a capturing group in your regex, why do you ask how to remove a char from a *capturing group*? Perhaps, you need to use one. Like in [`(@ABCD)\|(?!G)`](https://regex101.com/r/mHOtG3/1). Or [`(@ABCD)\|([^G])`](https://regex101.com/r/mHOtG3/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i know that i can repplace with $0 which matches the exact value from what the regex matches, but i dont want the | in it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this regex

```
^@[^|]*\K\|
```

and replace by:

```
" "
```

Explanation:

1. `^` marks start of a string
2. `@` matches @ sign
3. `[^|]*` matches anything but not pipe |
4. `\K` if match being found upto previous point, then \K makes the
   current position as starting point therefore the previous part wont
   be replaced
5. `\|` matches the pipe --> this pipe is going to be replaced

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fVTQjy/11)

Comment: so \K always sets the new "start" of the match if it finds something which is not `|` and once the | occurs it stops resetting the start?

Comment: \K forgets about the past matches and marks the current position as match... as everything upto \K were to find everything but not | , therefore we need to forget about everything that we don't need to replace. \K does this. From there on the next character is | thus it gets matched. and all match thing is going to be replaced by " " i.e empty space

Comment: and how come it only matches the first pipe? is it because of `^`?

Comment: let's first forget about \K, ^[^|]* means match everything which is not pipe from the initial point so it will match everything until |, as we know , thus I put a pipe | immediately to be matched and it get matched ... and i totally don't bother what comes after that matched | and don't even match anything

Comment: How can I use this with JavaScript API for Regular Expressions? I have watched your demo and it worked, but when I use it with JavaScript, then it always returns null! For example: 

var word = '@ABCD|NN12CT55|GFR';
 
let matchresult = word.match(/^@[^|]*\K\|/gm);
console.log(matchresult)

I tried exec, match, etc... but didnt work!